# How would you handle on demand revalidation with Nextjs static website using "next export"

Tags: firebase, next.js

I have a blog fetching data from a CMS, when new contents are added, and the page is viewed, it returns `404`

My folder setup is `/blog/[slug]/index.tsx` and the site is using `next export`.

On the page `/blog/[slug]/index.tsx`, I am using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to generate the dynamic page at build which works fine.

With `fallback: blocking`, When the site is deployed to Vercel, but when deployed to Firebase, it returns `404`, how do I fix this?

I saw a related question, but I would like to extend this how do I fetch post by slug without returning 404.

Next.js version: 12.2.5

Set fallback to blocking on `getStaticPaths`, try work with client side fetching with `useEffect` without getStaticPaths and getStaticProps, the page keeps reloading when deployed to vercel, on firebase, content is not showing as the function that fetches post by slug could not get the slug, and after a page reload it returns 404